# Continuity of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I proved that the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ at $x\neq0$ is continuous and want to extend continuity to $x=0$. Using polar coordinates I found that $\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x,y)$ is bounded by $\pm1$. Is there another way or is proving that function is not continuous with polar coordinates enough?

Comment: *Bounded by* proves nothing.

Comment: "want to extend continuity to $x=0$": what is your question ?

Comment: In polar coordinates with $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, this is just $f(x,y)=\cos\theta$. Which is not continuous at the origin, because it can take any value in $[-1,1]$ arbitrarily close to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do like
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+m^{2}x^{2}}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^{2}}}
\end{align*}
with the substitution that $y=mx$, the resulting limit varies with different $m$, the limit at $(0,0)$ of $f$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Along $y=0$, $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac x{|x|}\ne\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac x{|x|}$$ and the function cannot be continuous at the origin.